# Add to home screen gives 404 error in iphone

Tags: ios, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

My project is in reactjs progressive web app. When i do 
Add to home screen for iphone app displays 404 on opening.

While in android it is working fine.

In my local project it is working fine in iphone and android.
for live it is working fine in android but not working in iphone.

Here is my manifest.json file :

```
{
  "short_name": "My App",
  "name": "My App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "MY_App_Icon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "login",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Comment: Try to modify start_url to /login  or / in manifest

Comment: Shouldn’t start_url be an actual url?

Answer (score 0):

Setting start_url to `"start_url": ".",` should work

If you want to redirect to /login you will need to handle that in your application.